# The constructor LinkedHashMultimap is not visible

Tags: java, guava, multimap

The following code doesn't compile

```
import com.google.common.collect.LinkedHashMultimap;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkedHashMultimap<String, String> p = new LinkedHashMultimap<String, String>();    
    }
}
```

the error is: **The constructor LinkedHashMultimap() is not visible**

I have imported the google Java libraries, they are in the build path

and

```
        LinkedHashMultimap<String, String> p;
```

alone doesn't cause compile error... weird

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LinkedHashMultimap` has no public constructors and the way to get an instance is by using the factory method `create`. The reason for this is the loophole in Java Generics due to which type inference works only for methods and not for constructors. This means that instead of for example

```
LinkedHashMultimap<String, Map<String, List<String>>> = 
  new LinkedHashMultimap<String, Map<String, List<String>>>();
```

you can write

```
LinkedHashMultimap<String, Map<String, List<String>>> = 
  LinkedHashMultimap.create();
```

With Java 7 the pressure has subsided due to the "diamond operator".

Comment: sry, mind I ask you another related question, from {'foo':['bar1', 'bar2'], 'test':['ok']} , I could use create (2,2) right; first argument is the number of keys, second the number of values per keys, I don't understand your type inferences, I 'd like to end with a {'foo':'bar1', 'foo':'bar2', 'test':'ok'}

Comment: well seeing how it's done, I already have a Map<String, List<String>>,   and it seems this class doesn't  improve it

Comment: You can just use `create()`. Specifying initial capacity is just fine-tuning.

Comment: My example just uses arbitrary type parameters, whose only point is that they make the expression long. You wouldn't need to use it, just `<String, String>`, as you already have.

Comment: Another reason no public constructor: LinkedHashMultimap does not want  to be **extended**.

Comment: @卢声远ShengyuanLu Classes not wanting to be extended are declared **final**. `String` is a prime example of a class that must be absolutely impossible to extend for security reasons. It's got a handful of public constructors, though.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I mean extend outside of Guava.

Comment: But @卢声远ShengyuanLu, the class **does have** a `protected` constructor!

Answer (score 6):

Use the static [create](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/LinkedHashMultimap.html#create%28%29) method to get a new instance of LinkedHashMultimap.

```
    LinkedHashMultimap<String, String> p = LinkedHashMultimap.create();
```